# Want to embed a data as a json object in .net core and access it from angular

Tags: json, angular, .net-core, embed

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application with an Angular 6 front end. I am retrieving data through a controller and I would like to embed this data as a JSON object and access that data from the Angular application (not using an api call through a service). I have not found any clear posts on how to do this properly.

Comment: Please add more details what data format you want to exchange between angular and .NET ?

Comment: I am getting an a list of objects from entity framework. For instance List<Customer> customersList. I read this into the CustomerController.  I want to embed this list as a JSON object and map it to an array of Customer[] and access this information in the Angular application. However, I cannot use an api.